# can't set attribute 'columns' message trying to rename the columns in a df

Tags: python, databricks

I have a DF with many columns (about 100), I need to rename all of them. So I have done this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data.columns = ["ide_ads",  "ide_any",  "ide_sfdsdf"]  #this is a small part of all the fields
```

I got this message:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'columns'
```

With any other explanation. It says the error is in line 2. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is this your entire code? What is data?

Comment: is your dataframe called data?

Comment: Yes, data is my dataframe.

Comment: No, it is not my entire code.  I only wrote what I thought was important for my explanation.  This is the dataframe that was made some steps before in the code.  But, I have already solved my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved este problem.
The original idea was that if I have my **data** dataframe I can rename the fields with `data.columns = [new_name1,new_name2,...]` in order, but ir didn't work for me.
So, I finally solved it with instruction:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'A': 'X', 'B': 'Y'})
```

where A and B are the old names, X and Y are the new names.

I hope this can work for any of you.

Thank you very much.

Jose

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you answered your own question. If you want to modify your original data directly, here is a way: For method `.rename()`, you can set `inplace=True`. It will modify the dataframe directly instead of creating a new one (Reference: [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)).

Here's an example

```py
import pandas as pd

data.rename(columns={
    'old_column1': 'new_column1',
    'old_column2': 'new_column2'
}, inplace=True)
```